# PDO connect to SQLite server on different server

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I have a very simple SQLite database that I need to read/write to from a different server.

Say the database is stored here : http://www.abc.com/data/data.sqlite
And I'm using PHP to access it from http://www.xyz.com

So my first attempt was the following:

```
$dbpath = "http://www.abc.com/data/data.sqlite";
$dbconn = "sqlite:$dbpath";
$db = new PDO($dbconn)
```

No good, I get the following:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open database file'.........PDO->__construct('sqlite:http://w...') #1 {main} thrown
```

If try and copy the database onto the same server I'm accessing from:

```
$dbpath = "http://www.xyz.com/data/data.sqlite";
$dbconn = "sqlite:$dbpath";
$db = new PDO($dbconn)
```

I get the same message.
It's only when I give it a relative path on the same server:

```
$dbpath = "../data/data.sqlite";
```

That it actually works.
I know the database URLs and database itself are correct.
So is there a limitation to accessing cross-servers? Anyone know out to solve this issue?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

There are no such thing like 'SQLite server'. It exists only in a form of a file.
But there are no files in the HTTP protocol, but URIs only.
So, this is essential incompatibility.

To be able to do remote calls you have 3 choices

1. Only as a joke: download the file locally before each SELECT query and upload it back after updates
2. Establish some proxy script, to recieve a query and to return json.
3. Get yourself a real database server.
4. Or just change the project architecture to eliminate the need of remote access.

Comment: Or option 5, put the SQLite file on a network filesystem.  This results in all sorts of hilarious locking and concurrency issues, of course...