# Error accessing an SQLite db from a different location using PHP

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I'm stuck with this problem. I'm trying to access an `sqlite` database from a different location. So far I have tried using `PDO` to access such file. I've tried using `PDO` since from what I read here on SO that would be easier. I only want to do some select queries on the database.

```
 try{
  $DBH = new PDO("sqlite:192.168.48.52/data/log/localdb.db");
  echo "connected";
   }
  catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
   }
```

it outputs an error message saying '**SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open database file**'. I could access the location via SSH/putty or manually input the directory through a web browser. But not through PHP coded location. The file resides actually in a gsm gateway interface which has a -rw-r--r-- permission.

If I were to actually download the file and put it in my htdocs folder it does open the file and echos 'connected'

```
$DBH = new PDO("sqlite:localdb.db"); <--- **like this**
```

I also tried doing this since it requires some authentication to access the directory.

```
$DBH = new PDO("sqlite:admin:admin@192.168.48.52/data/log/localdb.db");
```

to no avail.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please check: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14478697/2737474

Comment: Just a brief explanation: sqlite is in form of a file so this does not support the HTTP protocol

Answer (score 0):

i think you miss 1 colon after the IP :

```
$DBH = new PDO("sqlite:admin:admin@192.168.48.52:/data/log/localdb.db");
```

Comment: Hey thanks for answering but it still doesn't connect :D I also tried entering the port number after the colon to no avail.